# Why Acrobat 11 does not show SWG animation?

Tags: pdf, viewers, media9

I am using `media9` package to import `SWG` animations to `PDF` file. E.g.

```
\includemedia[
    width=\textwidth,height=0.539930555556\textwidth, % scale=1.4,
    activate=pageopen,
    %addresource=Video/2012-04-03.swf,
    addresource=Video/2016-104-04.swf,
]{\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{2016-104-04}}{Video/2016-104-04.swf}%
```

Adobe Acrobat/Reader of version 10 on my laptop demonstrates the animations as expected as shows the following screen-short:

[image]

However Adobe Acrobat/Reader DC (i.e. Adobe v.11) on another computer shows only static picture:

[image]

Clicking on the Run button has no effect.

I tried also FoxIt Reader and it was successful on both computers. I am aware that Adobe Acrobat v.11 needs Flash Player to be manually installed and I did that. I also checked that all the above mentioned PDF viewers show same animations in `MP4` format which are included in the following way:

```
\includemedia[
    width=\linewidth,height=0.54\linewidth,
    activate=pageopen,%onclick
    addresource=Video/2016-104-04.mp4,
    flashvars={%
        src=Video/2016-104-04.mp4%
        &muted=true%
    }
]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{2016-104-04}}{StrobeMediaPlayback.swf}
```

**What's wrong with Adobe Acrobat 11?**

Comment: As Flash is about to phase out by the end of this year, Acrobat pops up a dialogue box every now and then, asking for the user's consent to stop running the Flash plugin altogether. It might be possible that, at some point, somebody had approved to do so already by clicking "ok".

Comment: @AlexG: What happens after the end of support for Flash plugins later this year? What video formats will media9 support?

Comment: I am going to look for a solution, perhaps outside `media9` and posted here.